# How do I use Ternary Operator within awk to write to a file?

Tags: awk

What is the syntax of Ternary in `awk` command in order to write to a file when condition is seen?

Below I'm trying but getting syntax error for given inputs!

Input sample data `infile.txt`:

```
1,1,c
0,3,b
0,0,a
1,5,z
1,5,y
5,5,x
```

The command:

```
awk -F',' '{print (($1==$2)?>"success.txt": >"failed.txt")}' infile.txt
awk: {print (($1==$2)?>"success.txt": >"failed.txt")}
awk:                  ^ syntax error
awk: {print (($1==$2)?>"success.txt": >"failed.txt")}
awk:                                                ^ syntax error
```

I can use `if/else`, but want to know the same with Ternary syntax possibility and maybe where am I using redirection `>` wrong?

```
awk -F',' '{if ($1==$2) print >"success.txt";else print >"failed.txt"}' infile.txt
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make the ternary operator choose only the file, not the redirection:

```
awk -F',' '{print >(($1==$2)?"success.txt": "failed.txt")}'
```